# Перенести процесс из swap в ram

Tags: linux, swap

Каким образом можно перенести только один процесс, память которого находится частично в swap пространстве, полностью в RAM (при условии что есть достаточно свободной RAM)?

Не отключая swap в системе, не меняя параметр vm.swappines, так как это будет влиять на все процессы находящиеся в свопе.

Причина - есть процесс mysql, к которому в будущем ожидается большой поток запросов и необходимо, чтобы к определенному моменту времени он был полностью в оперативной памяти.

Comment: если это не mysql, а всё-таки mysqld, то сделайте к нему sql-запрос.

Comment: Да, mysqld, но с тем же успехом это может быть другой демон запрос к которому сделать не представится возможным

Comment: пни его каким-нибудь сигналом

Answer (score 1):

Слишком непрактичная идея. 
У mysql есть опция -memlock  и с ее помощью можно избавиться  от своппинга.

Если это действительно так важно, все данные о памяти доступны через интерфейс /proc/ в linux. Если считать все байты, то, очевидно, все неактивное содержимое swap переместится в память. Вот тут есть примеры такой программы https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1401359/understanding-linux-proc-id-maps.

Comment: Пожалуйста, постарайтесь публиковать развернутые ответы содержащие конкретный пример минимального решения, дополняя их ссылкой на источник. Ответы–ссылки (как и комментарии) не добавляют знаний в Рунет.